# Nginx Proxy to multiple ports from same location

Tags: nginx

I currently have this configuration

```
server { 
listen 4000;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://websocket;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
upstream websocket {
    server localhost:4444;
}
upstream websocket2 {
    server localhost:4445;
}
```

With this configuration, all requests from localhost:4000 are being proxied to localhost:4444.
I don't want to proxy those request only to localhost:4444 but also to localhost:4445

localhost:4000 proxies requests to

- localhost:4444
- localhost:4445

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

From the Nginx documentation [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html),  you can declare an upstream with multiple servers. Then you can forward the traffic to this upstream and the traffic will be dispatched between servers. So just put your servers in 1 upstream `websocket` to archive what you want.

```
upstream websocket {
    server localhost:4444;
    server localhost:4445;
}

server { 
    listen 4000;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: While the configuration is valid, the requests seems to be proxied only to the first server in the upstream.